# What bike is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Edit:Posted all the photos that I have. Will post a better photo of the logo asap

No writing on this bike. Only identifying mark is a "G" logo on the front of the frame
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The photos are inadequate. All the major components will have model numbers on them. I.e. hubs, crank, brakes, derailleurs, shifters. You can examine these including taking proper photos which are legible .

Comment: Could you please add a clear photo of the logo, from straight in front ?

Answer (score 5):

It looks a lot like a Genesis GS700 with all the decals and reflectors removed and a different seat.

[image]

The [Amazon version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DIKI1S2) has the same seat but the crank isn't white.
[image]
According to the review of this bike at [bigboxbikes.com](http://www.bigboxbikes.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1156)

> Genesis (a Kent sub-brand)  ...  This bike shares it's frame with (at least) three other Kent bikes; the Giordano Libero road bike, and the GMC Denali Pro, and the Jeep Compass Hybrid. all of these bikes seem to have slightly higher components and drop handlebars, aside from the Jeep Compass.

> From Walmart's website:
> Genesis GS-700 Men's Flat Bar Road Bike
> Lightweight, handcrafted aluminum frame
> 21 speed (Shimano Tourney groupset)
> Shimano (Tourney) derailleurs
> (Promax) Linear pull V brakes
> 700c tires
> Steel hub
> Alloy high-profile rims
> Steel handlebars
> Weight: 27.5 lbs

Comment: 27.5 lbs is 'lightweight', sort of!

Answer (score 1):

Logo: Doesn't appear to be the G of Giant, which is pointier.   Also not a GT logo.  head tube badge

The tang on the inside of the G has a definite drop down, which I can't see on any bike logo.

---

The bike itself is a rigid commuter style, with MTB V brakes and plastic lever controls.  The frame looks like its made from Aluminium, and the fork could be anything.  The welds are not subtle.

The drivetrain is hard to see but appears to be a 3x7 or 3x8, so again MTB parts.  The BB seems to be an in-board threadded english pattern, so absolutely nothing special there.

Rims are a nice profile - they're aluminium and probably double-walled to get that shape.  Can't tell the size but guessing they are 622mm (29") or perhaps 27.5" wheels.  They do look totally rideable.

That there is a kickstand and the reflectors look clear and shiny still states pretty clearly that it hasn't had a lot of use.  Assuming tyres are original, its got no visible wear on the tread.

---

Upshot - I think its a department store brand bike - not anything fancy but totally adequate for riding on.

The only thing that looks bad is the saddle angle, consider levelling it a bit more and try that for comfort.